# How i can change text of the button on click with Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i am new to programming :)
I want change text to "Loading..." of the my button on the click with Angular, i have 1 way, but i need one more ways
My code:

html

```
<div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="full-width" [disabled]="subscribeForm.invalid"
                (click)="setLoading($event.target, 'Loading...')">Subscribe</button>
</div>
```

ts

```
 setLoading(element, text){
    element.textContent = text;
    element.disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the button text from typescript file. I also recommend you to get disabled state from typescript by a get method. In detail;

```html
<div>
  <button 
    mat-raised-button 
    color="primary" 
    class="full-width" 
    [disabled]="isButtonDisabled" 
    (click)="setLoading()">
      {{subscribeButtonLabel}}
  </button>
</div>
```

```js
// in your component class..
loading = false;
subscribeButtonLabel = 'Subscribe';

setLoading() {
  // you should set this values to their default for finishing loading state
  // you can either do this in a another method which you run on the success or fail scenarios for subscribtion.
  // Or you can use setTimeout to set back to default values after a certain time.
  this.loading = true;
  this.subscribeButtonLabel = 'Loading...';
  /*
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.subscribeButtonLabel = 'Subscribe';
  }, 1000); // sets back to default values after 1 sec.
  */
}

get isButtonDisabled(): boolean {
 return subscribeForm.invalid || this.loading;
}
```

Comment: You can even make more simplified, with taking label from loading state; `<div>
  <button 
    mat-raised-button 
    color="primary" 
    class="full-width" 
    [disabled]="isButtonDisabled" 
    (click)="setLoading()">
      {{loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Subscribe'}}
  </button>
</div>`
with this changes you can remove the `subscribeButtonLabel` property from class.